# Hibernate - joined strategy selects too many columns

Tags: java, postgresql, hibernate, jpa

We are using Hibernate 4.2.14 on JBoss eap 6.3, and PostgreSQL 12. On our app we are using "joined" inheritance strategy.

The problem appears when we query the superclass, then hibernate tries to join with all the subclasses of the inheritance and selects all the colums of all the subclasses, so then hits the "target lists can have at most 1664 entries" Postgres error.

Could using a discriminator column be the solution ? in that scenario hibernate will know which subclass to query and should join the superclass only with the specific subclass, avoiding the giant select which leads to error. is that possible ? are we missing something ?

Answer (score 1):

In Hibernate 5.4 this was optimized to only do joins that are really necessary, but there might still be situations how this can happen and I since you seem to be doing join fetches the update won't save you from this. You will have to use a different fetch strategy for some associations to reduce the amount of joins and select items. See here for more information: https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.4/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#fetching-fetch-annotation

If you also want to improve performance further by reducing the amount of columns to select, you could also rewrite queries to not use join fetching of entities but instead select only the entity fields you really need. This is a perfect use case for [Blaze-Persistence Entity Views](https://github.com/Blazebit/blaze-persistence#entity-view-usage).

I created the library to allow easy mapping between JPA models and custom interface or abstract class defined models, something like Spring Data Projections on steroids. The idea is that you define your target structure(domain model) the way you like and map attributes(getters) via JPQL expressions to the entity model.

A DTO model for your use case could look like the following with Blaze-Persistence Entity-Views:

```
@EntityView(A.class)
public interface ADto {
    @IdMapping
    Long getId();
    String getName();
    @Mapping("bCollection")
    Set<BDto> getBs();

    @EntityView(B.class)
    interface BDto {
        @IdMapping
        Long getId();
        String getName();
    }
}
```

Querying is a matter of applying the entity view to a query, the simplest being just a query by id.

`ADto a = entityViewManager.find(entityManager, ADto.class, id);`

The Spring Data integration allows you to use it almost like Spring Data Projections: https://persistence.blazebit.com/documentation/entity-view/manual/en_US/index.html#spring-data-features

Blaze-Persistence Entity-Views also supports the concept of fetch strategies

Comment: I've updated the question, hibernate selects all the columns of the subclasses, is that fixed on hibernate 5?

Comment: Is it possible tu run hibernate 5.4 on jboss eap 6.3 running jpa 2.1?

Comment: That is not fixed, no. That's just what needs to be done to fetch an entity. Maybe you should use a different fetch strategy for some associations.